# Editing gcode with vim regex

Tags: vim, regex

I need to edit gcode for a model in particular I have to substract number 87 from all Z coordinates.
Here is sample of gcode:

```
;LAYER:435
G0 F9000 X-38.420 Y-26.887 Z87.300
;TYPE:WALL-INNER
G1 F1800 X-37.709 Y-27.459 E1386.91774
G1 X-37.020 Y-28.062 E1386.94819
G1 X-36.404 Y-28.635 E1386.97618
```

From previous sample there is Z87.300 , which I need change to Z0.300 and do this for entire Z. I have tried following command in vim:

```
:%s/Z\(\d\d\)/\="Z".submatch(1)-87/
```

But it acts wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim evaluates your expression from left to right, so it first concatenates "Z" and the match, then subtracts 87 from the string (which yields 0). This can be fixed with parentheses:

```
:%s/Z\(\d\d\)/\="Z".(submatch(1)-87)/
```

To be more explicit (and handle decimal numbers that start with `0`), you can throw in `str2nr()`, like this:

```
:%s/Z\(\d\d\)/\="Z".(str2nr(submatch(1))-87)/
```

Comment: My solution was %s/Z\(\d\+\)/\='Z'.(submatch(1)-87)/
 since Z can be more digits.